# Fedora dnf update did not working?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, dnf

When I am trying to update my fedora 22 with update command

```
sudo dnf update
```

I am getting following error.

> Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates' from 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f22&arch=x86_64': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f22&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]

Comment: Is there internet connection on the machine?

Comment: yes, i have a working internet connection of 8 mbps.

Comment: Try this: `yum-deprecated update` (maybe dnf bug..)